# How to bind click event to button from ajax result

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have Button_1 that when click, it will request a new button_2 using ajax. Both button has click event on my jquery(document).ready but when the button 2 added to the page, it doens't have jquery event on it. Is that possible?

Here is my code on page load:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#button_1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get_button_2.php',
        data: 'id='+id,
        dataType: 'html'
    })
    .done(function(response){
        $('#button-container').html('');
        $('#button_1').remove(); // remove button 1
        $('#button-container').html(response).show('500');
    })
    .fail(function(){
        $('#button-container').html('Something went wrong');
    });

});


$('#button_2').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert ('Thank You!');
});

});
```

Comment: can you supply your current coding attempt?  Thanks!

Comment: hey @RobS. I edited my question and added my current code. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create the event on **DOM**.

```
$(document).on('click', '#button_2', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert ('Thank You!');
});
```

**REF:** http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This works! Thank you!

Comment: Nice! good luck coding!