# disable click after clicking on $('body').on('click') event

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi  I want to disable click after the user clicked  on an element

the elements loaded after my script (elements built by javascript) and I can't use these code

```
     $('.disableClick').click(
            function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            }
        )
```

and I use these code to do work on the element by click

```
    $('body').on('click','.disableClick',
                function (e) {
                    if(!is_valid)
                    {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            );
```

I think disabling click codes like e.stopPropagation()  don't support for

> $('body').on('click') 
>   event

Comment: For dinamic elements you need to use like this `$(document).on('click', '.element', function(){  [...]  })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind click event to button from ajax result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944236/how-to-bind-click-event-to-button-from-ajax-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('click','.disableClick',
            function (e) {

                   $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            }
        );
</script>
```

It works on `body` as well as on `document` both

Answer (score 1):

You need to use unbind I guess. 
Try

```
    if(!is_valid){
    $('selector').unbind("click")
    }
```